# Is it possible to overload operator<< like this?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Let's say I have a class called "Logger". The name is self explanatory, it logs stuff. I have a static method, which logs stuff (Logger::log(string msg)).
I wanted to overload the operator <<, so that I could do something like:

```
    Logger << "AW YEAH, I LOVE C++";
```

I tried to do this, but couldn't. What I managed, was this:

```
    Logger l; 
    l << ":(";
```

...

is it possible what I want to do? And if yes, how?

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual, formatted code?

Comment: @H2CO3: Although it seems to be a duplicate of this question, the answers to the referenced question seem to be all wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloaded operators operate on *values*, not on *types*.

Maybe you should rename your class, and then create a suitable global object. For example:

**logger.h:**

```
class mylogger { /* ... */ };

extern mylogger logger;
```

**logger.cpp:**

```
#include "logger.h"

mylogger logger;
```

Usage:

```
#include "logger.h"

logger << "Done";
```

Beware of global initialization issues; though; check out your implementation of `std::cout` for a way to solve this (e.g. with a Schwartz counter).

Comment: I don't think he needs the global... In the final usage example of what he wants he has: `Logger l; l << "(..."`, create a logger `l` and then call `operator<<` on that.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I doubt it. He says "all I managed was X, but I want Y".

Comment: My bad, I did not quite understand what he wanted. I was expecting something that made a bit more sense ;) (rather than a singleton of sorts)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It's no more a singleton that `std::cout` is...

Comment: Well seeing I can't achieve my goal, I find the idea of a global object atractive. It seems I'm not that pro at C++, don't quite follow what does `sdt::cout` has to do with the `operator<<`? And what are the issues?

Answer (score 1):

If `Logger` is the name of a class then of course you can't do that. Use something like

```
Logger &log() {
    static Logger l;
    return l;
}

log() << "And the answer is" << 42;
```

Comment: This is how Qt has a `qDebug` class.

Comment: Technically it's a macro, not a class. But yes, the principle is the same (return an object you can use `operator<<` on).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to leverage the output operators provide by `std::ostream` you should **not** try to overload the output operator! Instead, you'd create a suitable stream buffer (i.e., a class derived from `std::streambuf`) and implement your custom output logic in that class's `overflow()` and `sync()` methods. Your logger would then derive from `std::ostream` and initialize its base class to use your custom stream buffer.

Comment: Let's say I need this Logger in a game. Using 'std::ostream' will have unnecessary overhead, am I right?

Comment: I seriously wonder if *anyone* has ever derived from `std::streambuf`...

Comment: @VilmantasBašinovas: I'm assuming you aren't only interested in logging string literals (if that's the case, just overload `operator<<()` for you class taking a `char const*` as argument) but rather also want to get other types formatted which have an output operator defined (e.g., `int` or `double`): writing to an `std::ostream` is the best option to do so. I would also doubt that a reasonable amount of logging is the performance kill, even in a game! (not to mention that I can imagine things which have more serious time constraints than games...)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, I keep doing it quite frequently. Given that it is easy, I don't see any reason why people wouldn't do it. Also, I'm sure that I'm not the only one: it is the Right Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to figure out what interface you really want. One option is to make your `Logger` be an `std::ostream` (inheritance) and then things would kind of work out of the box. The alternative is to maintain a logger that is unrelated (no inheritance) to `std::ostream`, but then you need to provide `Logger& operator<<(Logger&,T const &)` for any and all types `T` you want to log. For the particular case of `std::string` you could do:

```
Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, std::string const& msg) {
   logger.log(msg);               // need not be, and problably should be static
   return logger;
}
```

Making this generic involves as with most generic code in C++ the use of templates:

```
template <typename T>
Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, T const & obj) {
   // do specific work based on the type, or a completely generic approach:
   std::ostringstream st;
   st << obj;
   logger.log(st.str());
   return logger;
}
```

At this point you might want to consider adding support for manipulators and... well, if you start down this path, it might make more sense not to create the `std::ostringstream` in each function, but create a single one as a member, then dump all data into that stream and use some manipulator to extract the string and write it (for example on `std::flush` or `std::ends`...)

```
template <typename T>
Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, T const& obj) {
   logger.stream << obj;
   return logger;
}
Logger& operator<<(Logger& logger, std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&)) {
   logger.stream << manip;
   if (manip == static_cast<std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&)>(std::flush)) {
      logger.write(); // flush to disk
   }
   return logger;
}
// add support for other manipulators...
```

Then again you might start wondering if it would not be easier to pull some off the shelf logging library and just use it.